# Is the unique_ptr returned from a function an lvalue?

Tags: c++11, unique-ptr

Lately, I've been doing a little digging into the C++11 std and was playing around with unique_ptrs.

Let's say I have a function which returns a unique_ptr to an integer.

```
unique_ptr<int> GetUniquePtr(int i)
{
   return make_unique<int>(i);
}
```

In my main function, I am able to take the address of the value returned by the function. This means that the expression must evaluate to an lvalue

```
int main()
{
   cout << &(GetUniquePtr(5));
}
```

I know if I assign the function call to a unique pointer, the move consturctor of the unique_ptr will be called, treating the returned value as an rvalue reference.

```
int main()
{
   unique_ptr<int> uPtr = GetUniquePtr(5);
}
```

This dual behaviour of returning unique_ptr kind of confuses me, as I was of the impression that unique_ptr returned from a function call is *always* evaluated as an rvalue.

Can anyone shed some light on what's actually going on?

Comment: [`error: taking the address of a temporary object of type 'std::unique_ptr<int>'`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9cd86585a124eb6d) -- as expected. What compiler and flags are you using?

Comment: No the result of the function is not an lvalue. You can't take the address of it like you attempt to (which you should have known if you tried to build the code). The second `main` function is okay, and then `uPtr` is an lvalue and you can get a pointer to it with the address-of operator.

Comment: @Quentin: I'm using visual studio community 17 to build the code. The settings are default as of now.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I obviously built the code. Don't be so quick to pass judgments

Comment: Disable language extensions, then. MSVC has an extension which allows taking addresses of rvalues (including binding them to lvalue references).

Comment: The title points at a flawed assumption. Whether the return value of a function is an lvalue doesn't depend on the specific class. `std::unique_ptr` obeys the same rules as `std::string`.

Comment: @MSalters Right of course,I was being specific intentionally, pointing out only what I observed. I know this doesnt just apply to std::unique_ptr

Comment: @Angew That did it, thanks

Comment: @Angew I had not thought of this because for raw pointers, the program was behaving as expected (taking the address of a raw pointer returned by a function would give a "not an lvalue" error)